# What is meant by discrete time plot with Whatsapp voice notes?

Tags: discrete-signals, wave

You might have noticed ,as shown highlighted in attached snap, whatsapp voice notes are bearing a discrete time plot

Is it exactly referring to sampled(discrete time)version of waveform of actual audio signal ?
[image]

Comment: How is something that has not even 1000 points supposed to be "exactly" the sampled audio waveform? that can't work for a sound snippet that is multiple seconds long. Other than that, we really can't know, it's closed source, and honestly, these things are mostly decorative more than anything else.